# SQL Query in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Age > ALL (SELECT Age FROM customers WHERE Salary > 6800);
```

Actually I am trying to learn the usage of ALL in SQL. But unfortunately when I am trying to execute this query it's giving me the error in XAMPP.
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "ALL" at position 36) Unexpected token.
>   (near "(" at position 40) SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Age > ALL ( LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

I would like to know what is the exact syntactical error in my query.
Here's my Table:
[Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kHa6.jpg)

Comment: You can't just throw code into MySQL and expect it to work. What do you mean by `ALL`?

Comment: Also: Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are totally different. Be careful about tagging things incorrectly.

Comment: ALL operator is used to select all records in a SELECT statement. It compares a value to every value in a list or results in a query. Error is still unidentified.

Comment: Yes, I know what it is, but it's something so rarely used I have to wonder why you're using it at all here. This is chock full of syntax errors, quite obviously. Try and get it working in smaller parts, build up from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing syntactically wrong with your query, you have an unfortunate version of `phpMyAdmin` which messes it up. The problem was present in 4.5.1, not present in 4.6.4, it was fixed some time in between.

This is the query that you send (OK):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Age > ALL (SELECT Age FROM customers WHERE Salary > 6800);
```

This is the query that server receives from phpMyAdmin (very wrong):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Age > ALL ( LIMIT 0, 25
```

Hence the problem.